# Android app-universal.apk fails to install on Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

My app uses the Zoom SDK. I was having trouble installing it on the Android emulator with an x86 system image (specifically, 23, 24, 25 on several devices), getting the error:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
```

I was able to solve this problem using a suggestion from another StackOverflow post, by putting the following in my `build.gradle`.

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

However, now in my `app/builds/outputs/apk` folder, there are multiple apk's being generated, namely:

```
app-arm64-v8a-debug.apk
app-armeabi-debug.apk
app-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
app-mips-debug.apk
app-mips64-debug.apk
app-universal-debug.apk
app-x86-debug.apk
app-x86_64-debug.apk
```

Edit: Creating a release build also creates these same versions, minus the 'debug' name, using 'release' instead.
According to the documentation,

> A universal APK contains code and resources for all ABIs in a single APK.

However, when I try to install the `app-universal.apk`, I fail with the same ABIS error as before.
I also tried to generate the release build, which failed with the same error.

Installing the `app-x86-debug.apk` on the emulator works just fine, however. So, it seems to me like the documentation on the universal apk does not seem to match the actual behavior.

Can someone explain to me how I can generate an apk that will run on both android devices and the emulator? If not, why am I not getting the expected behavior form `app-universal.apk`  ?

Comment: What happens, when you also try to build `x86_64`?

Comment: Build, or install? I just tried installing it onto the emulator, and it successfully installed. As for building, that happens automatically via Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You should add libraries in respective folders. 
There should be three or two folders under your libs based on how many you want to add.

```
arm64-v8a
armeabi-v7a
x86
```

If you do not have x86 and build the universal app, it will not install since this lib will be missing in the final package.

The app-x86-debug.apk will install since it will not have any native library version. But after installing app-x86-debug.apk your app will crash on emulator.